# Office Web Apps Server 2013

Tags: office-web-apps

I want to ask if any of here has a download link for Office Web App 2013? I'm searching for a link but I can't find one, I can only see the SP1 of it but not the exact installer of Office web app.

Please help, Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of 11-24-2014 Office Web Apps Server will be removed from the Microsoft Download Center.  At that time it will only be available for download under Volume Licensing agreements.

Download Office Web Apps Server from the [Volume Licensing Service Center (VLSC).](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?LinkId=256561) To download Office Web Apps Server you must have a license, under a Volume Licensing agreement, for Office Professional Plus 2013, Office Standard 2013, or Office for Mac 2011. The download is located under those Office products on the VLSC portal.

or

if you have the [MSDN subscription](https://msdn.microsoft.com) you can [download](http://www.akspug.org/Blog/Post/83/Office-Web-Apps-Server-Removal-from-Download-Center) it from their.

Comment: you welcome....